# Write a value with opc ua Python

Tags: python-3.x, opc

i trying write value  with this example :
[opc ua client to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55025311/opc-ua-client-to-server)

But i have this error :

```
 Exception "unhandled opcua.ua.uaerrors._auto.BadTypeMismatch"
"The value supplied for the attribute is not of the same type as the attribute"s value."(BadTypeMismatch)
File: C:\Users\lari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\opcua\ua\uatypes.py, Line: 218
```

someone can help me please

thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find \o/

this link help me : https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/issues/30

```
dv = ua.DataValue(ua.Variant(122, ua.VariantType.Int32))
dv.ServerTimestamp = None
dv.SourceTimestamp = None
trou.set_value(dv)
```

I hope my adventure can help others ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is telling you the server is expecting a value with a different datatype than the one you wrote.